# How to obtain all n atom fragments (substructures) from a mol file using RDKIT?

Tags: polymer, rdkit, molecule, cheminformatics

I am interested in obtaining fragments, or sub structures, that contain 4 non-hydrogen atoms within a larger molecule.

The closest example to accomplishing this is referenced from
https://iwatobipen.wordpress.com/2020/08/12/get-and-draw-molecular-fragment-with-user-defined-path-rdkit-memo/

I used their work but I don't believe "ALL" 4 atom substructures are found within their methodology. They use the concept of "radius" around centered atoms. This doesn't distinguish all possible substructures I am looking for.

Does anyone have suggestions for improving this code to obtaining my goal or a differing direction to go for future work?

I followed the method presented by the link above. Various substructures are presented but not 'ALL' 4 atom fragments are specified when running this method.

Specific Example:  [image: Major Structure I am using as Eample]

Substructure example I don't see using this methodology but I believe I should see at radii 1 or radii 2.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf4br.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf4br.jpg)

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
AllChem.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
```

```
def getSubmolRadN(mol, radius):
    atoms=mol.GetAtoms()
    submols=[]
    for atom in atoms:
        env=Chem.FindAtomEnvironmentOfRadiusN(mol, radius, atom.GetIdx())
        amap={}
        submol=Chem.PathToSubmol(mol, env, atomMap=amap)
        subsmi=Chem.MolToSmiles(submol, rootedAtAtom=amap[atom.GetIdx()], canonical=False)
        submols.append(Chem.MolFromSmiles(subsmi, sanitize=False))
    return submols
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C')
```

```
submols = getSubmolRadN(mol,1)
Draw.MolsToGridImage(submols, highlightAtomLists=[[0] for _ in range(len(submols))], molsPerRow=5)
```

```
submols = getSubmolRadN(mol,2)
Draw.MolsToGridImage(submols, highlightAtomLists=[[0] for _ in range(len(submols))], molsPerRow=5)
```

```
submols = getSubmolRadN(mol,3)
Draw.MolsToGridImage(submols, highlightAtomLists=[[0] for _ in range(len(submols))], molsPerRow=5)
```

Outputs for Radii 1 and 2, radii 3 I obtain an error[image: Outputs of radii 1 and 2]

Comment: "that contain 4 non-hydrogen atoms within a larger molecule" this is not specific enough I guess. Do you want to have 4 non-hydrogen atoms within a specific radius within the molecule? Do you want to have 4 non-hydrogen atoms connected by one or multiple carbons? Right now I can give you code that checks whether or not your example structure has 4 non-hydrogen atoms. The output for your example structure would be True. Or do you want to find every Carbon atom that is connected to 4 non-hydrogen Atoms?

Comment: Thank you for your questions. I am looking for all substructures that contain 4 atoms that are not hydrogen. A differing way to say this is explaining in terms of bonds. I would like all fragments that contain 3 bonds where hydrogen atoms are not apart of the 4 atoms or 3 bonded substructure. Regarding the radius question, I am not looking explicitly at "radius" more so all the substructures that contain 4 atoms and 3 bonds. In graph theory, generally hydrogens are ignored and the other atoms are counted as nodes which I am trying to exercise here.

Comment: Additionally, I believe I found the function that does this for me. RDKit rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthMToN

Answer (score 3):

To find 4 connected non-hydrogen atoms you can use `SMARTS`.

Since a connection of 4 can be linear or have one branch and must not end with hydrogen (important if you have explicit hydrogen), these two SMARTS should work.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw, rdDepictor
rdDepictor.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
IPythonConsole.molSize = (200, 150)

smarts_linear = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[!#1]~*~*~[!#1]')
smarts_branch = Chem.MolFromSmarts('[!#1]~*(~[!#1])~[!#1]')
```

`smarts_linear`

[image]

`smarts_branch`

[image]

For better testing I will use a molecule with explicit hydrogen.

```
mol = Chem.AddHs(Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C'))
mol
```

[image]

```
sub_linear = mol.GetSubstructMatches(smarts_linear)
sub_branch = mol.GetSubstructMatches(smarts_branch)
all_subs = sub_linear + sub_branch

found_subs = []

for n in range(len(all_subs)):
    found_subs.append(mol)

Draw.MolsToGridImage(found_subs, molsPerRow=4, highlightAtomLists=all_subs, subImgSize=(200,150))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previous user (rapelpy) answered the question as well. A team member of mine was able to generate a code as to obtain the paths or subgraphs. To clarify, paths don't have branching where subgraphs do.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
AllChem.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem import rdmolops
import csv

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C=C(S)C(N)(O)C')
mol


# Find all subgraphs of length 3 in the molecule
#Subgraphs have branching
subgraphs = Chem.FindAllSubgraphsOfLengthN(mol, 3)

#Paths is no branching
#subgraphs = Chem.FindAllPathsOfLengthN(mol, 3)
print(len(subgraphs))

# Print out the connected SMILES for each subgraph
for subgraph in subgraphs:
    # Get the subgraph as a new molecule object
    sub_mol = Chem.PathToSubmol(mol, subgraph)
    # Generate the connected SMILES string for the subgraph
    subgraph_smiles = Chem.MolToSmiles(sub_mol, kekuleSmiles=True)
    print(subgraph_smiles)

Output
11
C=CCC
C=CCO
C=CCN
C=C(C)S
CCCS
OCCS
NCCS
CC(C)O
CC(C)N
CC(N)O
CC(N)O
```